How to reserve EventHub partitions for special workloads?
In our platform we have traffic from clients (where processing time is important), and traffic from import migrations (where processing time is not important)
The downside of these two types of traffic feed into the same workload, is that the import migrations and huge and will often 'block' the high priority traffic.
So in EventHub, we were wondering whether we can use say, 10 partitions for client traffic, and 2 partitions for imports.
Is it possible to achieve such a setup? For example to be able to specify that an event should either write to 1-10, or 11-12, based upon the traffic type?

I wouldn't recommend that pattern, but there's no technical blocker.
This got longer than I intended, so I'll start by saying that I'd recommend using a separate Event Hub for your high priority traffic over trying to specialize partitions.
But, could I?
Yes.  There's no blocker to doing you're suggesting, assuming that you control the publishers and can coordinate them assigning a specific partition at the time they send data.
What could go wrong?
Partitions in Event Hubs are the fundamental unit of concurrency.  They exist to help segment data so that both producers and consumers can scale.  You generally don't want to treat them as filters for different types of data, as it makes it more difficult to scale and places a burden on both publishers and consumers to "follow the rules."
One key concern is introducing "hot partitions" - meaning that events are clustered into a subset of partitions rather than being evenly distributed.  This hinders the application's ability to scale and reduces overall throughput since one partition generally has one reader.  This constraint is enforced by some clients like the event processor in the Azure SDK libraries.
Unless you have a very evenly distributed and predictable load coming in, publishers would have to have some central point of coordination to ensure that they were distributing data evenly.  For an Event Hub, this is generally the service gateway, which performs round-robin distribution for you.  Since you'd be looking to use only certain partitions, the gateway couldn't be used and your application would have to take on that responsibility.

Very helpful answer, thank you!
